# Is there a way that us initial / beta users can see site stats, like questions-per-day, etc?

Tags: support, site-promotion, recent-activity, statistics

I saw one of SE's [beta sites go from beta to flop](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business).  The post-mortem statistics were interesting: strong activity, except for the questions.

I think this kind of insight can be valuable, in knowing where best to push to stimulate a fledgling community.

- Do we have access to those kind of stats 'live'?
- Is it only for "founding-mods"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we do, over at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation):

[image]

Comment: That is not live data.

Comment: @called2voyage When I looked a couple of hours ago, we were at 70% answered. Now we're at 73%. Also, we had 16 avid users; now we have 17. If's it's not live, it's certainly close to it.

Comment: It's also not complete. It may or may not be what OP wants. If he's talking about more detailed trends, those are only available to moderators.

Comment: @called2voyage The link he posted is to the exact same stats, for Startups.

Comment: That's true, but he also said that he wanted something more "live" depending on how he means "live" he could be looking for something different.

Comment: I believe by "live" he meant "before the site dies". I could be wrong though; let's wait and see what the OP says :)

Comment: You're probably right. I probably just misread it the first time. I just thought I'd point out that if he's looking for something more, it's restricted to mods.